# High network usage in network monitor

Tags: c#

I have a program which displays network usage in two `Labels`. I use an `NetworkInterface` array to get all network interfaces. The problem is that the network usage is way to high (95 MB for received/s). I looked into the interface array and noticed that there where a lot of interfaces listed there. I don't know why but I think this is because the network at the company where I work is very complex, it goes through several proxies and servers before "reaching" the internet.

If my assumption is correct, how can I filter out the needed interfaces (LAN and/or WLAN)? I looked into the properties but cannot see any useful information.

```
private void updateNetwork()
{
    if (interfaces != null)
    {
        long received = 0;
        long sent = 0;

        foreach (NetworkInterface netinterface in interfaces)
        {

            received = received + netinterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
            sent = received + netinterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent;
        }

        label1.Text = "Received: " + received;
        label2.Text = "Sent: " + sent;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I assume BytesReceived is an absolute value not per second.

Comment: dude in fact you are right. ok I am feeling really stupid now, it hadn't event crossed my mind that it could be a total value. is there any way with which to display the per-second value?

Comment: Using WinCap could work.

Comment: Read BytesReceived twice measure the time between those two reads and do some math too normalize the value to seconds. Or use the PerformanceCounter class to get the values for your Interface from PerfMon.